# Clip raster along grid in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, clip

I have a topographic map of Washington as a TIFF-file from the US Geological Survey. And I'd like to clip the raster to the extent of the outer grid lines (78E/39N, 76E/39N, 76E/40N, 78E/38N). So that the map information (legend, projection, etc.) disappear. How can I realize that in ArcGIS?

[image: Here you can see the map]

Is there maybe a way to create a grid as a polygon and to cut the raster along this polygon? Which other possible ways are there?

Comment: Is the TIFF georeferenced? If not, do the clip in Photoshop or Gimp and then georeference the map. Otherwise, create a polygon around the area you need to clip and clip it that way.

Comment: The TIFF is georeferened. I created a polygon along the outer grids and it worked. Thank you!